# QGIS Print Composer Templates

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Whenever I launch QGIS 2.18.23 all my template print composers launch in the background without any prompting and I'm unable to close them [image]

How can I switch them off or close them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Project - manage print compositions` - there you may remove compositions from your project - which in my opinion is to be recommended, since compositions slow down the start-up of your project significantly. If you need to print something, you always can load a template of the desired map-size.